# Updating an entity with linq to sql, do I need to call attach first?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

My code looks like:

```
Entity e = new Entity();

e.name = "...";
e.blah = 234;

MyDb.UpdateEntity(e);


public static void UpdateEntity(Entity e)
{
    using(MyDatacontext dc = new MyDataContext())
    {

          dc. ?????????
    }

}
```

So what do I do here to update the entity?

note: i just called it entity here, its something else in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your data context. Normally you will have an object for each table in your database. So for example if you have a database that has an orders table you will have an Orders object in your DataContext (created by dragging the table into your dbml file in the designer).

So for a new order you woud do the following:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext()) {
    ctx.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);

    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

And to save an order passed to your client and modified ther you do:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext()) {
    ctx.Orders.Attach(order, true);

    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dc.GetTable<Entity>().InsertOnSubmit(e);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx

Comment: `dc.InsertOnSubmit(e)` is not valid, as the `InsertOnSubmit` operation is a method of the Table class. I.e. you need to do `dc.Etities.InsertOnSubmit(e)`.

Comment: @Obalix Yea..I saw that too. Woops. :)

Comment: @Obalix `dc.Entities` would be cleaner, but I like having a generic repository, so `GetTable<T>` works better for me.